# Open File dialog shows a renamed folder

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, internet-explorer, namespaces

I recently renamed a directory in the "My Pictures" folder from "ghostAlbum" to "imageAlbum"

Explorer shows what I would expect (the new folder) as does the command line "dir" command.
Excel's and Word's open file dialog show the same thing explorer does.

Internet Explorer's file open dialog shows the renamed folder, as well as an icon for the same folder with the prvious name.

Hopefully the images here explain it.  If not let me know any I will attempt to clarify.  I don't even know where to start figuring this out so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Explorer]
[image: CMD]
[image: IE dialog]

I checked both locations assigned to the Pictures library (..\Users\family\Pictures, and ..\Users\Public\Pictures), neither contain an item named "ghostAlbum" that I can see via Explorer.exe or cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try ***dir /a:HS*** and find your 'missed' files/folders.

This folders have a HIDDEN (or even SYSTEM) attribute set. By default dir command not list such files.

BTW: AFAIR option "Show hidden and system files" are disabled in Windows Explorer by default, so seems you (or some software) have changed this setting before.

Comment: Good thought, however the very first thing I change on new OSes is to turn off hiding hidden files/folders.  Also, as a verification I ran your dir command and there's nothing there.

Comment: Sorry, *dir /a:HS* will show you hidden files. It should be *dir /a:DHS* for diresctories.

Comment: Yes.  I am quite familiar with the command line and dir.  There are no hidden folders.

Comment: Also, the premise of your answer is flawed.  If it was a matter of hiddenness, the open file dialog would not show the folder.  The OFD shares its idea of visibility with explorer.